# How to get and set yline in iText 7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

In iText 5, by using ColumnText we're able to get and set yline of the text. I'm wondering if we can do the same thing in iText 7. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In iText7 one can set fixed position of `ElementPropertyContainer` and thus define the bottom (y line) of an element.

In your  case you probably want to set the position of a paragraph:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("x 100, y 100").setBorder(new SolidBorder(1);
p.setFixedPosition(100, 100, 100);
```

The resultant pdf looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get the value of yline for the paragraph?

Comment: The anwer depends on how you interpret getting the yline of a paragraph. You can always get the value of the Property.BOTTOM property (which is used to place a paragraph if FIXED position is set. But even in this case you cannot be 100 % sure where the element will be placed.

In general you cannot get the position of an element before it's placed. But you can always emulate the placement and then get the element's coordinates. The code below may give you a hint on how to do it

Comment: `paragraph.createRendererSubTree().setParent(doc.getRenderer()).layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(0, new Rectangle(10000, 10000))));`

Comment: In the snippet abote one tries to place a paragraph on 10000x10000 sized page. then one can consider the result of the layout call (LayoutResult) and the renderer's occupiedArea/other properties